# How to test whether Pusher channel is triggered in ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, mocking, pusher

I have the following method in a model:

```
  def trigger_events_updated_push_event
    Pusher['events'].trigger('events_updated', {})
  end
```

I have the following spec:

```
   describe '#trigger_events_updated_push_event' do
      it 'should send message to Pusher' do
        Pusher['events'].should_receive(:trigger).with('events_updated', {})
        subject.send(:trigger_events_updated_push_event)
      end
    end
```

Which produces this error:

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
       (#<Pusher::Channel:0x007ff16f18ae58>).trigger("events_updated", {})
           expected: 1 time
           received: 0 times
```

What am I failing to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At first your code needs improvement. You hardcoded another Class/Constant in this class that makes it tightly coupled.

Refactor at first

```
def trigger_events_updated_push_event(event=Pusher['event'])
  event.trigger('events_updated', {})
end
# This way you allow other kinds of event to be injected.
```

Then test.

```
it "fires event" do
  event = double
  event.stub(:trigger).with(anything)
  event.should_receive(:trigger).with('events_updated', {})
  subject.trigger_events_updated_push_event
end
# Your test is only about this Class and does not depend on Pusher at all.
```